# Problemas con la dirección de Metadatos Servicio Web WCF

Tags: c#, webservice, wcf

Tengo un Web Service que se publicó en un servidor, quedando algo parecido al siguiente link

http://192.168.1.20:8080/WSPagos.svc

El problema se está presentando que a la hora de compartirlo y querer consumirlo desde otro proyecto en Visual Studio, no se puede agregar la referencia, ya que los links del archivo wsdl aparecen con el nombre del servidor, por lo cual el Visual Studio no puede resolver la dirección:

http://nombreServidor:8080/WSPagos.svc?wsdl

Traté de descargar el archivo wsdl y cambiar "nombreServidor" por la IP en las direcciones Web, pero siempre intenta acceder a los datos y en algún momento se llega a topar con la dirección http://nombreServidor:8080/WSPagos.svc?wsdl.

Sí alguien me puediera ayudar con respecto a saber como debo proceder, sí existe algún campo en el web.config que deba de agregar o cambiar.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola. Has probado a editar tu archivo `Hosts` que se encuentra en `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc` poniendo el nombre del servidor y esa IP?

Comment: Eso serviría, pero no es una buena opción, ya que habría que hacer lo mismo en cada en cada equipo que quisiera consumir el WS, la idea es que sea siempre la dirección IP

Comment: Ya intentaste declarar en la definición de los contratos un namespace? éste se refleja hacia el wsdl. otra opción es agregar un base address en el web config

Comment: Hola. Puedes descargarte el `wsdl` en una ruta local del equipo de desarrollo y generar un cliente usando dicho archivo en vez de comunicarse con el servicio. Para crear un cliente lo importante es la definición del servicio, no dónde está alojado. Puedes modificar el archivo `wsdl` para que tengas la IP en vez del nombre del servidor.

Comment: Hola, puedes generar el `wsdl` de la siguiente forma para que toda la definición esté en un único archivo. `http://nombreservidor:8080/WSPagos.svc?singleWsdl`.

Answer (score 1):

En la configuracion de [iis](/questions/tagged/iis) en `Site Bindings` edita el `Host Name` con la IP